# How to transform a nested objects using jq?

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have a json object of the form:

```
{
  ...
  objectx: {
    nested_obj1: {
      key1: value1
    },
    nested_obj2: {
      key2: value2
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

. I need to add a `keyX: valueX` to all the `nested_obj`s in `objectx` using jq.

I was trying to apply a map filter using `.objectx | map(.+{keyX: valueX})` but could not figure out how to store this filtered list into the original json object. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the objects you wish to update (the values of the `objectx` object) and set the value you want. `map` is designed to work on arrays, not objects. `map_values` can be used for that instead.

```
.objectx |= map_values(.keyX = $valueX)
```

Personally I prefer do this:

```
.objectx[].keyX = $valueX
```

Note that using `[]` on an object will yield all values of that object.